# Empty content after WP_Query()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin which calls a specific page.  Below code works fine and calls the page inside my modal, but for some reason rest of the page doesn't execute after using this code and returns empty:

```
        $args = array(
          'p'         => 33, // ID of a page, post, or custom type
          'post_type' => 'any'
            );

        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        <?php 

        wp_reset_postdata();
        endwhile;
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks,

Comment: Put `wp_reset_postdata();` after `endwhile;`

Comment: I did, still same

Answer (score 0):

try wp_reset_query(); instead of wp_reset_postdata(); after endwhile;
this may can work for you.